# React-leaflet GeoJSON: change color of the layer after state

Tags: leaflet, geojson, style, features, react

I have an issue, I have a react-leaflet map with GeoJSON layers. Also, I have added some state components like cascader with some name of countries options, like Austria, Belgium, etc... I want to have it like this. After the state from cascader is done (so after I click on a country in cascader), I want to change the color of the selected country from that cascader and display it on the map. For example, if I choose Austria, I want to have colored Austria on the map. Also cascader is from the Ant Desing library. And `selectedCountries` is another state that is not important.

```
const [currentValueCascader, setCurrentValueCascader] = React.useState([])

function onEachCountry(country, layer) {
    const countryName = country.properties.ADMIN

      if (currentValueCascader.includes(countryName)) {
        layer.setStyle({ fillColor: 'yellow', weight: 2, fillOpacity: 5 })
      } else {
        layer.setStyle({ color: "#000000", fillColor: "white", weight: 1 })
      }
}

return(
<Cascader
                showSearch
                style={{ width: 256 }}
                options={countries}
                onChange={(e) => {
                  setCurrentValueCascader(e)
                }}
                placeholder="Search country"
                value={currentValueCascader} 
                multiple
    
    
              /> 
<MapContainer
            style={{ height: "80vh", width: "auto" }}
            zoom={2.3}
            scrollWheelZoom={true}
            minZoom={2.3}
            center={[30, 0]}>
            <TileLayer url='https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png' />
            <GeoJSON data={features} onEachFeature={(a, b) => { onEachCountry(a, b, selectedCountries) }} style={(a, b) => { onEachCountry(a, b, selectedCountries) }}}  />
          </MapContainer>
    )
```

I think that somehow the Leaflet map is not re-rendering that chosen option or maybe that GeoJSON, but don't know how to solve it.

Comment: I'm not familiar with React, but if it's OK with you, I can post answer for plain JS and HTML.

Comment: U can try it, maybe it will help.

Comment: There some work needed for this, so unless you are sure it'll be helpful to you, I won't post it.

Comment: I am sure that it will help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways how to deal with this. Since I'm not familiar with React, answer will be for plain HTML/JS. Country name is being input through `input` HTML tag:

```
<label for="country">Country:</label>
<input type="text" id="country" name="country">
```

**First possibility** is to leave setting the style as you have done it. If the style is set with `onEachFeature` option function, then style is set only once, at the time of GeoJSON data load. To change style at the time country name input, all features/countries have to be iterated and style set again according to selected country name. Group layer method `.eachLayer` can be used for this.

Plaing HTML/JS code could then look something like this:

```
var inputElement = document.getElementById('country');

function onEachCountry(feature, layer) {
  const countryName = feature.properties.name;

    if (inputElement.value.includes(countryName)) {
      layer.setStyle({ fillColor: 'yellow', weight: 2, fillOpacity: 5 })
    } else {
      layer.setStyle({ color: "#000000", fillColor: "white", weight: 1 })
    }
}
$.getJSON( "data/countries.json")
 .done(function(data) {
   var vectorLayer = L.geoJson(data, {
     onEachFeature: onEachCountry
   });
   map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
   inputElement.addEventListener('input', function(evt) {
     vectorLayer.eachLayer(function(layer) {
       onEachCountry(layer.feature, layer);
     });
   });
 });
```

**Second possibility** is to use GeoJSON layer `style` option to set layer style and then GeoJSON layer `.setStyle` method to set style again when country name is selected.

In this case code could look something like this:

```
var inputElement = document.getElementById('country');

function countryStyle(feature) {
  var style;
  var countryName = feature.properties.name;
  if (inputElement.value.includes(countryName)) {
    style = { fillColor: 'yellow', weight: 2, fillOpacity: 5 };
  } else {
    style = { color: "#000000", fillColor: "white", weight: 1 };
  }
  return(style);
}

$.getJSON( "data/countries.json")
 .done(function(data) {
   var vectorLayer = L.geoJson(data, {
     style: countryStyle
   });
   map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
   inputElement.addEventListener('input', function(evt) {
     vectorLayer.setStyle(countryStyle);
   });
 });
```

To avoid iterating through all the layers/countries each time country name is changed, **third possibility** would be to build translating table/object between country name and corresponding Leaflet layer id, retrieved by `.getLayerId` method. This way country layer for desired country can be directly accesses with the help of `.getLayer` method.

In this case code could look something like this:

```
var inputElement = document.getElementById('country');

function countryStyle(feature) {
  return({ color: "#000000", fillColor: "white", weight: 1 });
}

var selectedCountry = null;
var countryToLayerId = {};

$.getJSON( "data/countries.json")
 .done(function(data) {
   var vectorLayer = L.geoJson(data, {
     style: countryStyle
   });
   map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
   vectorLayer.eachLayer(function(layer) {
     countryToLayerId[layer.feature.properties.name] = vectorLayer.getLayerId(layer);
   });
   inputElement.addEventListener('input', function(evt) {
     if (selectedCountry) {
       vectorLayer.resetStyle(selectedCountry);
       selectedCountry = null;
     }
     if (countryToLayerId[inputElement.value]) {
       selectedCountry = vectorLayer.getLayer(countryToLayerId[inputElement.value]);
       selectedCountry.setStyle({ fillColor: 'yellow', weight: 2, fillOpacity: 5 });
     }
   });
 });
```